# Group objects with similar data and reformat with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Javascript Group array of objects with similar data and reformat with mongoose

mongoose get item in array in aggregate project

I have an array of objects which I want to group to produce this result

```
data:[{
        user_name: 'Jenny Lawrence',
        inner_data:[{
            "Back Pack":"Black",
            "produced":"2019",
            "manu_year":"2019",
            "item_state":"produced",
            "expiration":"unknown"
        },
        {
            other data belonging to jenny lawrence is formated like above
        }]
        "inner_data":{
            "detail":{"personal_item":"Baseball",
                    "manu_year":"2015","item_state":"purchased","color":"White","expiration":"unknown"}}
    }]
```

This is the data

```
"data":[
    {"user_name":"Jenny Lawrence", "inner_data":{
        "detail":{"personal_item":"Back Pack","manu_year":"2019","item_state":"produced",
                    "color":"Black","expiration":"unknown"}}},
    {"user_name":"Steven Benjjy",
        "inner_data":{
            "detail":{"personal_item":"Sneakers",
                    "manu_year":"2019","item_state":"purchased","color":"White","expiration":"unknown"}}},
    {"user_name":"Steven Benjjy",
        "inner_data":{
            "detail":{"personal_item":"Baseball",
                    "manu_year":"2018","item_state":"purchased","color":"White","expiration":"unknown"}}},
    {"user_name":"Jenny Lawrence",
        "inner_data":{
            "detail":{"personal_item":"Baseball",
                    "manu_year":"2015","item_state":"purchased","color":"White","expiration":"unknown"}}},
    {"user_name":"Jenny Lawrence",
        "inner_data":{
            "detail":{"personal_item":"iPhone",
                    "manu_year":"2019","item_state":"purchased","color":"White","expiration":"unknown"}}},
    {"user_name":"Daniel Stone",
        "inner_data":{
            "detail":{"personal_item":"Android Phone",
                    "manu_year":"2019","item_state":"purchased","color":"Stone grey","expiration":"unknown"}}},
    {"user_name":"Daniel Stone",
        "inner_data":{
            "detail":{"personal_item":"iPad",
                    "manu_year":"2019","item_state":"refurbished","color":"White","expiration":"unknown"}}}]}
```

I want to group the items by username and make the data in personal_item as a name and color's value as the data/value and do the same thing for
item_state and manu_year, but put the others in their normal format all as an object of an array.

How can I get this done in mongoose

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MongoDB's aggregation framework with certain stages/operators :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** group on user_name & push data to inner_data field */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user_name",
      inner_data: {
        $push: {
          /** merge existing 'inner_data.detail' with new fields */
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$inner_data.detail",
            {
              /** As certain fields are being formed as an array, convert those to k:v pairs */
              $arrayToObject: [
                [
                  {
                    k: "$inner_data.detail.personal_item",
                    v: "$inner_data.detail.color"
                  },
                  {
                    k: "$inner_data.detail.item_state",
                    v: "$inner_data.detail.manu_year"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /** Optional, but this stage can be helpful to remove unnecessary fields */
  {
    $project: {
      "inner_data.color": 0,
      "inner_data.personal_item": 0
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oPfQYTdPM2k)

**Ref :** [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) , [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html)

Above query gives same structure of **inner_data** for all users, in case if you need that kind of transformed **inner_data** structure only for **Jenny Lawrence**
& for rest other users the same old **inner_data** then try this :

```
/** All the difference it brings is conditional check before push */
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user_name",
      inner_data: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$user_name",
                "Jenny Lawrence"
              ]
            },
            {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$inner_data.detail",
                {
                  $arrayToObject: [
                    [
                      {
                        k: "$inner_data.detail.personal_item",
                        v: "$inner_data.detail.color"
                      },
                      {
                        k: "$inner_data.detail.item_state",
                        v: "$inner_data.detail.manu_year"
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "$inner_data"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "inner_data.color": 0,
      "inner_data.personal_item": 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wNd5l24y1Cf)